# Overflow protection for numbers jax-rs

Tags: java, jax-rs, query-string

With @Path variables it is possible to stop overflow conversions (from string to number).

For example if a parameter is an integer (int) then a path expression like **{number : \d{1,5}}** is a breaker before doing a number conversion.

What about handling query parameters in a similar fashion?  The syntax for path variables isn't usable in the @QueryParam annotation (**@QueryParam("big : \d{1,5}") big...**).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Introduction:* The path parameters guide the request to the correct method, and therefore a big flexibility is needed for that. The request parameters (GET/POST/...) on the other side need to be validated, i.e if a request contain invalid parameter value, you should take care of that.

*Solution:*

- Beginning with JAX-RS 2.0 (published in May 2013 with the reference implementation Jersey 2.0) you have support for validation. Check this [examples](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html).
- Before JAX-RS 2.0 (probably your situation) you should do the validation manually, e.g by injecting an int or long and checking its limits.

Comment: thanks will check out the 2.0+ examples.  Using pre 2.0.